# How do I use the blend tool after the isometric rotate effect?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

[image]

Hello, When I try to blend the front and last words, the middle words get a box around them. Does anyone know why this happens and what to do? I used Effect > 3D and Materials > Rotate...

Comment: I think you must Expand the effect before using the blend tool.

Comment: Just reverse your blend direction. Just rearange the objects before the blend.